# How do I use this method? (the method takes a text file and convert it into a string)

Tags: java

I'm currently in a High School level Java course. I've been doing plenty of research here, on Stack Overflow, trying to work through a project i'm currently assigned. The project consists of making modifications to, and searching through, various words pulled from an encyclopedia file. This is what I am having trouble with, the very basic form of this project. I already found the method in which to solve this problem, but i wasn't able to find a good way of implementing it. This is a copy of the code i found here: (the third method down contains the portion i took from this site)

```
class word
{
    public String newString;
    EasyReader fileIn = new EasyReader("Encyclopedia.txt");
    EasyWriter fileOut = new EasyWriter("writeHere.txt");
    String fileName="Encyclopedia.txt";
    private String onFile;

    public word()
    {
        onFile="";
    }

    public word(String s)
    {
        onFile=s;
    }

    String file = "Encyclopedia.txt";
    private String readFile(String file) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line=null;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String is=System.getProperty("line.seperator");

        while((line=reader.readLine())!=null)
        {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
            stringBuilder.append(is);
        }

        newString=stringBuilder.toString();
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

So, the question: how do i use this method? i know it sounds silly, but how do run this method and then use the data later? It is supposed to take a given text file and return a string, but i'm not even sure how to get the return value after it has processed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I made an account here just to ask this question. If i need to post this somewhere else, or if there is a better site to use to find an answer and some more basic help, please let me know. Thanks,
-Ethan

Comment: Given the fact that it's `private`, you'd have to call it from the constructor, probably `word(String)`

Comment: how would i call this method? Usually, im used to doing something like class.methodName(arg) but i'm not really passing an argument or data, i'm just tyring to get it to generate the string... I'm new to java, sorry if i'm saying something stupid.

Comment: Since this method returns a result, you call like a function: `String myString = readFile( "myFileName" );`

Comment: From within the constructor something like `String data = readFile(s);`.  When calling instance methods from within the same instance of the class, you don't need to supply the class/object name

Comment: thank you all for the help. I think i saw something like this on another topic and was just looking at it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `readFile` method seems to be doing multiple things at once. It accepts a `file` argument which overrides the member variable with the same name. Then it reads the file into a String and sets the `newString` member variable to the result before returning the same result.

So I would recommend first deciding whether the method should return the data or set the member variable. If multiple methods are going to be using the result, it might be useful to use the member variable, otherwise go the return route. Also, you can probably remove the `file` member variable since it is ignored by the method.

You can rewrite the method to look like this (I just removed the `newString=stringBuilder.toString();` line, and I changed it to static since it can be):

```
private static String readFile(String file) throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line=null;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String is=System.getProperty("line.seperator");

    while((line=reader.readLine())!=null)
    {
        stringBuilder.append(line);
        stringBuilder.append(is);
    }

    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

And wherever you need to use it call it like this (remember to catch the IOException):

```
try {
    String someString = readFile("filename.txt");
} catch(IOException e) {
    // handle error
}
```

Remember it must be called from inside the same class unless you change `private` to `public`.

Also, it might be worth reading and following a standard [code style](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html). It can really help by distinguishing between different types of variable for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 String file ="/path/to/file.csv"
 word myWord  = new word();
 o = myWord.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("readFile");
 o.setAccessible(true);
 Object r = o.invoke(myWord);
    //print result
```

Comment: `readFile` is private, it can't be called from outside of the instance of the class it was defined in

Comment: The poor OP has no idea how to call a method from within the class it's defined and you shove reflection onto them!?  That's a really bad idea (IMHO)

Comment: agree but it is better to have multiple ways of doing what OP wants to do and he could choose the one he feels comfortable in.

Comment: I might agree if reflection wasn't discouraged generally but completely circumventing the access control is a complete hack. Guiding the OP to a more appropriate solution, as provided by StanleyKou for one or suggesting making the method `protected` or `public` would have been far better solutions.  This is just a complete dirty hack that should be avoid where ever feasibly possible

Answer (score 0):

Actual method that read string from file is: "readFile". And in your class, you are not calling that.

```
private String readFile(String file) throws IOException
```

You can pass file name as parameter, and It will returns read string.

So, how about modify your word(String s), and add method that will return actual result of read file?

```
public word(String s)
{
    onFile=s;
    newString = readfile(onFile);
}

public getNewString(){
    return newString;
}
```

Comment: i tried this out and received the error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught       newString = readFile(onFile);             would you mind helping me with the location of where i would add the try/catch?

Comment: again, i'm really new to this kind of thing. going all out in an explanation would be highly appreciated

Comment: Add try/catch for catch IOException. And let me show your error message. It seems that file path is wrong, so you need to place "Encyclopedia.txt" to proper path.